# Need to get serialized data from a form

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm new to prototypejs. Can you guys tell me how to get serialized values from a posted form using Ajax in prototype?

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

http://prototypejs.org/api/form/serialize

Or you want to handle a form through ajax instead of page load? then

http://prototypejs.org/api/form/request

Comment: Firstly i need to convert into json format, so i need to serialize and get the values using ajax without page load.

Comment: $('yourform').serialize(true) will serialize to json for you, and then you can send it with ajax, or you can use $('yourform').request() which will serialize AND send it for you.

Comment: I'm trying to do like this way as you said, but i'm not getting any values displayed in the console. but alert message is appearing $('customerdetails').request({ method: 'get', onComplete: function(details) { alert('Form data saved!');console.log(details.responseText); }})

Comment: what if you do console.log(arguments) ? Maybe the XHR object is the second parameter, not the first. Albeit this already works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/NquDR/

Answer (score 0):

"how to get serialized values from a posted form using Ajax " Makes it sound like you're expecting the Ajax *response* to include the serialized data sent to the server, but what the response contains is entirely up to the server. Typically, once you make an Ajax request, the `onComplete` handler doesn't really care about the properties that it sent. The `response` argument to the `onComplete` (and any other Ajax callback) contains a `request` property, which contains `parameters` object. This would be useful if you did indeed need to see what your request sent to the server, like so:

```
$('customerdetails').request({
    method: 'get',
    onComplete: function(response) {
        console.log(response.request.parameters); // What you sent to the server
        console.log(response.responseText); // What the server sent back to you
        console.log(response.responseJSON); // JSON-ified version of what the server sent back
    }
});
```

It's possible for `response.responseJSON` to be `null` if Prototype isn't sure that the response actually contains JSON (if, for instance, the response headers were improperly set). If you can bank on the response being JSON, you could do something like this:

```
onComplete: function(response) {
    var jsonObj = response.responseJSON || response.responseText.evalJSON();
    // now you can work with jsonObj
}
```

Hope this helps and I didn't just completely misunderstand your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Ajax.Request('your_ajax_url',{
   method:'POST',
   parameters:Form.serialize($('your_form_id'))
});
```